# Check if date in field is after date in another field

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, datetime, sql

I want to check if a field in one data extension is greater (after) a field in another data extension.

I currently have 
`op.[EventDate] > (acc.[Most_Recent_Auto_Loan_Application__c]+14)` within the query but it's not returning any results - these fields are data/time data types, and my assumption is that I'm missing something because of the data type.

If anyone has any suggestions for a fix it would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable/799616#799616) way to approach it -- one that handles the time portions of the date-times.

```
op.eventDate > convert(date, acc.[Most_Recent_Auto_Loan_Application__c]+13)
and op.eventDate <= convert(date, acc.[Most_Recent_Auto_Loan_Application__c]+14)
```